# HtmlUnit Class Cast Exception: TextPage cannot be cast to HtmlPage

Tags: java, spring, htmlunit

I am trying to test my web page using spring MVC test and HTMLUnit. I need to get Html Page so that I can set value in my page and submit it but I got the following exception. How can I achieve this? Am I proceeding the right way? Please consider me as I am newbie to TDD.

**Error Stack Trace:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.TextPage cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage
    at com.demo.htmlunit.test.LoginControllerHtmlUnitTest.userLoginTest(LoginControllerHtmlUnitTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

And my Test Class is:

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.htmlunit.MockMvcWebConnection;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPasswordInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
@WebAppConfiguration
public class LoginControllerHtmlUnitTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private WebClient webClient;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        System.out.println("In set Up");
        MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
        webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.setWebConnection(new MockMvcWebConnection(mockMvc));
    }

    @After
    public void cleanup() {
        this.webClient.closeAllWindows();
    }

    @Test
    public void userLoginTest() {
        try {
            // Load the Login Form
            System.out.println("In User Login Test");
            HtmlPage createLoginFormPage = webClient
                    .getPage("http://localhost:8080/htmlunitdemo/login");
            System.out.println("createLoginFormPage:"+createLoginFormPage);
            // Setting Values in the Login form
            HtmlForm form = createLoginFormPage.getHtmlElementById("loginForm");
            HtmlTextInput usernameInput = createLoginFormPage
                    .getHtmlElementById("username");
            usernameInput.setValueAttribute("admin");
            HtmlPasswordInput passwordInput = createLoginFormPage
                    .getHtmlElementById("passcode");
            passwordInput.setText("admin123");
            HtmlSubmitInput submit = form.getOneHtmlElementByAttribute("input",
                    "type", "submit");
            // Submitting Form
            HtmlPage newPage = submit.click();


            System.out.println("New Page:" + newPage.asXml());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="true">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.htmlunit.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that HTML Unit is not able to cast incompleted HTML Pages (some unclosing tags, for example). So, I could solve this error using HTMLParser which is included in HTMLUnit's packages (I'm using 2.36.0v). HTMLParser completes and handles this kind of casting errors.

```
//Web client creation.
Page page = webClient.getPage(url);
HtmlPage tmpPage = HTMLParser.parseHtml(page.getWebResponse(), webClient.getCurrentWindow());
// use tmpPage here
```

Answer (score 1):

```
HtmlSubmitInput submitBtn = currentPage.getFirstByXPath("//input[@value='Search']");

currentPage = submitBtn.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

HtmlUnit doesn't care at all about the `applicationContext.xml` or your Java server code. All it matters to it is the output the server generates. If the output is random text then HtmlUnit will assume it is fetching a text file and will create a TextPage to process it. If the output is HTML then HtmlUnit will assume it is getting an HTML file and create an HtmlPage to hold the result. Based on your question you clearly need the latter.

So verify the output from your server application (`http://localhost:8080/htmlunitdemo/login`) and make sure it outputs valid HTML code.

Comment: The URL"http://localhost:8080/htmlunitdemo/login" is valid html file. If I comment
// webClient.setWebConnection(new MockMvcWebConnection(mockMvc));
this code in setUp() section the code works fine.

Comment: The issue is exactly the same. HtmlUnit doesn't care where the request comes from. Make it a URL or a mocked connection, if the content is not valid HTML it won't be able to create an HtmlPage. Now, if the code works fine without that line... why don't you remove it?

Comment: Actually, I want to mock the WebConnection object. If I remove the code, the connection is not mocked and the server must be started to run the test which is not fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

replace code line:

```
 HtmlPage newPage = submit.click();
```

with:

```
 TextPage newPage = submit.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I already find the solution. The error occurs when the button is Submit, not if it is a button type.
I solved it by adding a button and executing it.

```
HtmlElement buttonCustom = (HtmlElement) page.createElement("button");
            buttonCustom.setAttribute("type", "submit");
            buttonCustom.setAttribute("name", "submit");
            buttonCustom.setAttribute("value", "Load");
            form.appendChild(buttonCustom);
```