# HtmlUnit for javascript code results in not-updated TextPage instead of HtmlPage

Tags: javascript, dojo, htmlunit, headless

I seem to be having a somewhat similar issue to ["HtmlUnit Class Cast Exception: TextPage cannot be cast to HtmlPage"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774241/htmlunit-class-cast-exception-textpage-cannot-be-cast-to-htmlpage)

But am not able to use some of the tips such as HTMLParser.parseHtml.  I think the interface has changed for it.

My main problem is not getting back the updated javascript from the webClient.  The page text is only the original source in the .html file invoked with getPage(url).  It also is only in TextPage format and cannot convert to HtmlPage.  These two issues are likely related.

Here is my Java source:

```
String url = action.getScriptURL();
System.out.println("url:"+url);

// tried .CHROME as well as leaving default
try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX)) {

    webClient.getCache().clear();
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(true);
                   
    Page page = webClient.getPage(url);  // should have javascript updates here, but maybe not yet
    // not valid: HtmlPage htmlPage = (HtmlPage)webClient.getPage(url); 
    //String pageStr = htmlPage.asText();
                                
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000); 
       
    int tries = 5;  // Amount of tries to avoid infinite loop
    while (tries > 0) {
        tries--;
        System.out.println("trying again: "+tries);
        try {
           synchronized(page) { // page
               page.wait(20000);  // How often to check - page
        }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
               System.out.println("exception waiting for page"+ex);
        }
    
        if (page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString().contains("f_collectionLib"))
         break;

        page2 = webClient.getWebWindows().get(0).getEnclosedPage();
                       
        System.out.println("HTML page?:"+page2.isHtmlPage());
    }       

    boolean hasUpdate = page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString().contains("Collection Library");
    System.out.println ("html page hasUpdate:"+hasUpdate); 
        
    webClient.close();
 }
```

So why is my content from the server not in htmlPage format?
And why is it not updated?

I can go to the same html URL in my browser and go into debug and see the JavaScript has been run there.
[html in debug on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwmlK.png)
[screen after accessing URL directly in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJuFx.png)

When I use page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString() it returns the same text as is in the original .html file.

I feel like I have tried all the tips I have found on waiting and setting options.  I am obviously missing something...

For getting the results in htmlPage format,
If I try to convert it to htmlPage, I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.TextPage cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage
> at com.ibm.PDIScript.runDojoChart.export(runDojoChart.java:395)
> at com.ibm.PDIScript.runDojoChart.main(runDojoChart.java:154)

i
body of the html:

```
<body class="claro histTheme">
<!--catch JavaScript errors for later retrieval -->
<!-- to capture use: ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return window.jsErrors");-->
<script type="text/javascript">
window.jsErrors = [];
window.onerror = function(errorMessage) {
  window.jsErrors[window.jsErrors.length] = errorMessage;
}
</script>

<!-- set Dojo configuration, THEHn load dojo.js -->
<script>
    var dojoConfig = {
        async: true,
        has:{'dojo-bidi': true},
        //dojoBlankHtmlUrl: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + "/blank.html",
        packages: [{
            name: "hist",
            location: "/SystemiNavigator/com/ibm/as400/pt/hist"
        },{
            name: "dojoChart",
            location: "/SystemiNavigator/com/ibm/as400/pt/dojoChart"
        }
        
        ]
    };
</script>
<!-- load dojo FIRST -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/auiruntime8106/dojo/dojo/dojo.js" ></script>
<script>
    require([
        "dojo/parser",
        "dojo/ready",
        "hist/utils",
        "dojoChart/DojoGraphScript",
        
        "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
        "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
        "dijit/TitlePane",
        "dojox/layout/TableContainer",
        "dijit/form/TextBox",
        "dijit/form/CheckBox",
        "dijit/form/Textarea",
        "dijit/form/NumberSpinner",
        "dijit/form/FilteringSelect",       
        "dijit/form/TimeTextBox",
        "dijit/form/DateTextBox",
        "dijit/form/Button",        
        "hist/widget/SelectableChart",
        "dijit/form/Button",
        'dojo/dom', 'dojo/on', 'dojo/domReady!'
    ], function(parser,ready,utils,DojoGraphScript) {
        
        ready(function(){
        // Invoke the dojo/parser to process the dijit layout widgets specified in the body declaratively
        parser.parse();
        var rtl = utils.isRTL();
        if(rtl){
            dijit.byId("mainBC").dir = 'RTL';
            dojo.style(dijit.byId("mainBC").domNode,"direction","rtl");
            dijit.byId("TitleBar").dir = 'RTL';
            dijit.byId("titleLeftPane").dir = 'RTL';
            dijit.byId("titleCenterPane").dir = 'RTL';
            dijit.byId("titleRightPane").dir = 'RTL';
            dijit.byId("titleRightActionPane").dir = 'RTL';
            dijit.byId("leftPane").dir = 'RTL';
            dijit.byId("leftTopPane").dir = 'RTL';
            dijit.byId("leftTopTitlePane").dir = 'RTL';
            dijit.byId("leftBottomPane").dir = 'RTL';

            var link2 = document.createElement("link");
            link2.type = "text/css";
            link2.rel = "stylesheet";
            link2.href = "/auiruntime8106/dojo/gridx/resources/claro/Gridx_rtl.css";
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link2);
        } else {
            var link2 = document.createElement("link");
            link2.type = "text/css";
            link2.rel = "stylesheet";
            link2.href = "/auiruntime8106/dojo/gridx/resources/claro/Gridx.css";
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link2);
        }
        
        var pGraph = new DojoGraphScript({isRTL: rtl});
        
        pGraph.postCreate();
        console.debug("pGraph.postCreate()");   
        
        });
    });
</script>
    
<!-- load dojo -->  
<div data-dojo-type="dojoChart/DojoGraphScript" ></div> 
   <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" id="mainBC" data-dojo-props="region:'center'">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" id="TitleBar" data-dojo-props="region:'top'" style="height:30px; background-color:#cce6ff;">        
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="titleLeftPane" data-dojo-props="region:'leading'" style="width:140px;padding:0px;background-color:#cce6ff; border:none;overflow:hidden;">
                 <div id="ActionButton" style="padding:0px;"></div>
           </div>
           <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="titleCenterPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'" style="padding:0px;background-color:#cce6ff; border:none;">
                   <div id="Title" style="padding-top:6px;"></div>
           </div>
           <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="titleRightPane" data-dojo-props="region:'trailing'" style="width:30px;padding:0px;background-color:#cce6ff; border:none;"></div>
           <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="titleRightActionPane" data-dojo-props="region:'trailing'" style="width:40px;padding:0px;background-color:#cce6ff; border:none;"></div> 
        </div>  
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" id="leftPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center',splitter:'true'">
             <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="leftTopPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'" style="height:150px;border:none;">
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit.TitlePane" id="leftTopTitlePane">
                    <div id="filtersTableContainer" style="width:925px;overflow:auto;"></div>
                    <div id="buttonsContainer"></div>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="leftBottomPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'" style="padding:0px;">
                <!-- id="selectableChartContainer" style="width:100%;height:100%;" -->
                <div id="chartGridContainer" style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow-y:auto"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

DojoGraphScript.js constructor and postCreate:

```
            constructor: function(args  ){ 
                var urlParms = utils.getUrlParms();
            this.packageId = urlParms.packageId;
            this.perspectiveId = urlParms.perspectiveId;
            this.basePerspId = urlParms.basePerspId;
            this.perspectiveName = urlParms.perspectiveName;
            this.colName = urlParms.collectionName.trim();
            this.library = urlParms.collectionLib.trim();
            this.colType = urlParms.collectionType.trim();
            this.colFormat = urlParms.collectionFormat.trim();
            this.fileLevel = urlParms.fileLevel;
            this.startTime = urlParms.startTime;
            this.endTime = urlParms.endTime;
            this.systemName = urlParms.systemName.trim();
            this.release = urlParms.release;
            this.GUIInterval = urlParms.GUIInterval;
            this.collectionInt = this.GUIInterval;
                console.log("collectionName:"+this.colName+ " type:"+this.colType+" format:"+this.colFormat);
                    if(this.GUIInterval == undefined || this.GUIInterval == "---"){
                    this.GUIInterval = -1; 
                }
                this.viewType = 'dojo';
                this.viewNum = 1;           
                    console.log("Constructor dojographscript.js");
                
            lang.mixin(this, args);
            },

            /** postCreate - function called after DOM has been created" +
             * This is where it all begins.
             */
            postCreate: function(){
                    console.log("postCreate dojographscript.js");
            dijit.byId("leftTopTitlePane").set("Title","TITLE:helloWorld");
            dom.byId("buttonsContainer").innerHTML = "Hello World";
            
                    
/*              dijit.byId("leftTopTitlePane").watch("open", function(param, oldValue, newValue) {
                    var leftTopPane = dijit.byId("leftTopPane");//border container
                    leftTopPane.resize({h: (newValue ? 150 : 28)});   
                    dijit.byId("leftPane").resize(); //
                });

                aspect.after(registry.byId("leftPane"), "resize", function(changeSize, resultSize){
                    if(resultSize != undefined && resultSize[0] != undefined && resultSize[0].w != undefined){
                        var leftTopTitlePane = dijit.byId("leftTopTitlePane");
                        leftTopTitlePane._layout({w: resultSize[0].w});
                    }
                });
*/
                var args = '{action: "helloWorld", perspectiveId: this.perspectiveId}';
                this.processHelloWorld(args);

            //var args = {action: "getContextMri", perspectiveId: this.perspectiveId};
            //var callbackFunc = dojo.hitch(this,'processContextInfo');
            //  console.log("before exit postCreate dojographscript.js");
            //this.callServer(null,args,callbackFunc); // calls for context panel
                
            },
            
            processHelloWorld: function(theJsonString) {
                this.theJsonString = theJsonString;
                console.log("json string 11.0:"+theJsonString);
                
                //document.write("<div>" +"11 args" 
                 //   + "<div>"+theJsonString+"</div><div>");
            },
```

Comment: Can you please add the url you are using to help us reproducing your case.

Comment: yes - url:http://xxxxxx:2004/SystemiNavigator/com/ibm/as400/pt/dojoChart/HelloWorldScriptLauncher.html?packageId=IBM_CS&perspectiveId=P_SYS_SUMMARY_CPU_WAITS_OVERVIEW&perspectiveName=CPUUtilization and Waits Overview&collectionName=TEST1&collectionLib=PDI&collectionType=Collection Services File Based Collection&fileLevel=54&startTime=Aug 31, 2020 3:22:09 PM&endTime=Sep 1, 2020 12:00:11 AM&systemName=A405BP4 &release=V7R4M0&collectionFormat=*CSFILE&basePerspId=

Comment: sorry, it is not a publicly available site

Comment: This is the javascript:

Comment: DojoGraphScript.js: `constructor: function(args  ){ 
var urlParms = utils.getUrlParms();
//...this.viewType = 'dojo';
console.log("Constr");
lang.mixin(this, args);
},   
postCreate: function(){
console.log("postCreate");   dijit.byId("leftTopTitlePane").set("Title","TITLE:helloWorld");
dom.byId("buttonsContainer").innerHTML = "Hello World";
var args = '{action: "helloWorld", perspectiveId: this.perspectiveId}';
this.processHelloWorld(args);
},   
processHelloWorld: function(theJsonString) {
this.theJsonString = theJsonString;
console.log("json string 11.0:"+theJsonString);},`